# Convergence of proper integral

Tags: analysis, convergence-divergence, definite-integrals

I need to prove that this integral converges or diverges. I think I need to use

$$-1\leq\cos x\leq1$$

but I am not sure what to compare it to. This is the integral

$$\int_{1}^{2}\frac{3\cos(2x+1)}{(x-1)^{2/3}}dx.$$

Comment: Why do you think that the fact that you always have $-1\leqslant\sin x\leqslant1$ is useful for the study of an integral in which the sine function does not appear?

Comment: When $x$ approached $1$, can you find an equivalent of $3\cos(2x+1)/(x-1)^{3/2}$

Comment: @Atmos That would be $\frac{3}{(x-1)^{2/3}}$ ,correct?

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos sorry I meant cosx!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The integral converges absolutely. Just use $\lvert \cos(y) \rvert \leq 1$ for all $y \in \mathbb{R}$ and then compute:
$$
\int_1^2 \left \lvert\frac{3\cos(2x+1)}{(x-1)^\frac{2}{3}} \right \rvert~\mathrm{d}x \leq 3 \int^2_1 \frac{1}{(x-1)^\frac{2}{3}}~\mathrm{d}x = 9(x-1)^\frac{1}{3} \bigg \vert^2_1 = 9 < \infty
$$

Answer (score 1):

Your integrand only has a possible problem near $x=1$. From the bound that you suggests,
$$
\frac{3\cos(2x+1)}{(x-1)^{2/3}}\leq \frac{3}{(x-1)^{2/3}}
$$
and so all boils down to the integrability of $\frac{1}{(x-1)^{2/3}}$ over $(1,2]$. Here you have
$$
\lim_{a\rightarrow1+}\int^2_a\frac{dx}{(x-1)^{2/3}}=\lim_{a\rightarrow1+}3(x-1)^{1/3}|^2_a=\ldots$$